# Programmierung: Bindestrich zwischen Klassenname und dem Wort "Klasse"?

Tags: compound, hyphen

Ich schreibe eine Thesis über eine in C++ implementierte Software. Hier beschreibe ich verschiedene C++ Klassen, was in etwa so aussieht:

> Die Thread-Klasse kapselt die ...
>
> Die Start()-Methode erzeugt einen neuen Thread...

In diesem Beispiel ist "Thread" der Name der Klasse und "Start" der Name einer Methode der Klasse.

Was ist die korrekte Schreibweise für "Thread-Klasse" und "Start()-Methode", mit oder ohne Bindestrich?

Wie ist es mit:

> Die Methode Start() erzeugt einen neuen Thread...

?

**Update:** Die Klassen- und Methodenname werden durch eine "*nichtproportionale Schriftart*" hervorgehoben:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kurze Antwort: Bindestrich ist richtig, und bei der »Methode ›Start()‹« müssen zusätzlich Anführungszeichen oder Kursivsetzung oder vergleichbares als Auszeichnung stehen. Jemand wird schon bald mit der entsprechenden Dudenparagraphregel antworten, denk ich.

Comment: @Jan: Besondere Hervorhebung ist nicht unbedingt nötig. Ich kann auch vom Nutzer Jan berichten, es muß nicht der Nutzer „Jan” sein.

Comment: @chirlu Nicht zwingend nötig, aber zu empfehlen. Ich finde, das Update sieht richtig gut aus.

Comment: Typographischer Hinweis: Der Bindestrich sollte aus der Grundschrift sein. Auf den Bildern sieht es so aus, als wäre es der aus der Festbreitenschrift.

Comment: @chirlu Danke für den Hinweis. Es ist ein 'hyphen' (aus der Grundschrift), ein 'en-dash' wäre hier besser, richtig?

Comment: Nein, auf jeden Fall Bindestrich (_hyphen_). Wenn es die Grundschrift ist, ist es richtig; ich kann es nur nicht richtig erkennen.

Comment: Ich denke formal wäre es richtig die runden Klammern bei den Methoden wegzulassen und wenn ein Text sich an Nichtprogrammierer richtet würde ich es auch so machen, ab wg. des hohen Wiedererkennungswertes halte ich die Klammern dann doch für gerechtfertigt, denn leichte Lesbarkeit ist ja das Ziel guten Schreibens und die Regeln sind geronnene Erkenntnisse über gutes Schreiben, deren Verletzung mit guten Gründen daher gerechtfertigt sein kann. Aber Wehe jmd. versucht dieses Argument gegen mich zu wenden, dann lösche ich diesen Kommentar. Wie schreibst Du, wenn die Parameterliste nicht leer ist?

Comment: Nebenbei: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Thesis

Comment: @userunknown Auch wenn die Methode Parameter hat, lasse ich diese im Text weg und schreibe einfach nur "()".

Comment: @CarstenS Sorry, ich kann deinem Hinweis nicht folgen...

Comment: @sergej, ich würde an der Stelle das Wort „Thesis“ nicht verwenden.

Comment: Ich würde @userunknown recht geben, die Klammern gehören in den meisten Sprachen nicht zum Methodennamen und werden normalerweise weggelassen. Gerade in C++: Hier sind Operatoren auch Funktionen, du hast also einen `operator()` als Funktionsname! Um dort nicht `operator()()` schreiben zu müssen und trotzdem einheitlich zu bleiben, sollte man konsequent darauf verzichten. Die Parameterklammern können da stehen, wo es explizit um einen Aufruf geht: *„Ein Aufruf von `Join()` blockiert …“*

Comment: Stephen T. Lavavej allerdings [schreibt in Microsoft's VC++-Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/14/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-part-2.aspx) Funktionsnamen immer mit Klammern, inkl. `operator()()`, was der Unterscheidbarkeit von Klassen zugute kommt. Es geht also beides wirklich gut.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Zusammensetzungen, die fremde (meist englische) Wortgruppen enthalten, werden mit Bindestrich geschrieben, d.h. nicht eingedeutschte Wörter werden korrekterweise mit Bindestrich<sup>[(1)](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Bindestrich/Fremdwort.html#Anchor-Nomen-49575)</sup> in zusammengesetzte Substantive eingebaut, also

> die Thread-Klasse und die Start()-Methode.

Der Bindstrich darf nicht entfallen, so dass ein Gebilde aus zwei extra groß geschriebenen Wörtern entstehen würde.<sup>[(2)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190430104525/https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Zusammengesetzte-Substantive)</sup>

Korrekt ist auch "Die Methode Start()" zu verwenden.

Comment: Manche englische Wörter sind im Deutschen schon so weit integriert, dass man sie bei Zusammensetzungen schon wie deutsche Wörter behandeln kann, wie z.B.: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Online_

Comment: Dann leidet aber die Einheitlichkeit. Die Startmethode einer Threadklasse könnte ja auch eine Methode sein, die nicht 'Start()' heißt und in einer Klasse vorkommen, die ein Thread ist, aber auch nicht so heißt. Hier unterstreicht die Schreibung, dass die Elemente auch so heißen, wie sie bezeichnet werden.

Comment: Die alternative Konstruktion ist fast immer vorzuziehen. "Die Programmiersprache C++" ist unermeßlich viel besser als "Die C++-Programmiersprache" (auch wenn der Verlag anderer Meinung war).

Comment: @userunknown: Und das Schriftbild leidet mit, wenn für die Bezeichner bei der Schreibweise in einem Wort dennoch eine andere Schriftart verwendet wird - `Start`methode, `Thread`klasse.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das ist dann aber ein Wasch-mich-aber-mach-mich-nicht-nass-Problem. Wenn man die exakte Schreibung hervorheben will, dann ist das Mittel dazu ja gerade die Störung des Leseflusses. Du kannst nicht beides haben - eine smoothe Uniformität und Hervorhebung. Die runden Klammern bei Methodennamen würde ich jedenfalls weglassen, oder würde man auch schreiben "die Start(at: DateTime) - Methode"? In den seltensten Fällen ist es nötig, den Leser zu behandeln als sei er lernbehindert, wenn weit und breit keine zweite Startmethode da ist, mit der man die in Rede stehende verwechseln könnte.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn benannte Entitäten beschrieben werden, sollte man überhaupt keine Bindestrichkonstruktion einsetzen, wie Kilian Foth bereits in einem Kommentar schrieb.

Bei zusammengesetzten Nomen steht rechts das Kopfwort, was normalerweise angibt, was etwas *ist*. Links davon steht ein beschreibendes Wort. Wikipedia hat [eine Liste](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)#Typisierung_von_Nomina_nach_semantischen_Mustern) von gebräuchlichen Mustern dafür.

Kein solches Muster ist es, den *Namen* einer Entität mit deren Art zu einem zusammengesetzten (wenngleich mit Bindestrich getrennten) Wort zu verbinden.

Es ist völlig legitim, „der OK-Button“ oder „eine Thread-Klasse“ zu sagen. Das sind in diesem Fall Beschreibungen. Nicht gut ist „die `Thread`-Klasse“ o.Ä., denn so etwas kommt ansonsten auch nie vor: Nicht „der Rhein-Fluss“, sondern „der Fluss Rhein“, nicht „der AF-447-Flug“, sondern „Flug AF 447“ – **und daher immer „die Klasse `Thread`“**.

Sobald das Wort einmal als Klassenname etabliert ist, kann die Art weggelassen werden: „Um `Thread` zu instanziieren, ...“.

Um die Verwirrung komplett zu machen: Eine Instanz von `Thread` könnte dann wieder als ein „`Thread`-Objekt“ bezeichnet werden.

Mal ganz davon abgesehen, dass `Thread` ein furchtbar aussageschwacher Name für eine Klasse ist.

Comment: Das Beispiel "der Rhein-Fluss" ist gut. Da muss ich mal drüber nachdenken. Danke.

Comment: Die Thread-Klasse ist aber keine Entität, sondern ist der Typ aller Entitäten mit Thread-Eigenschaften, dessen instanziierte Objekte dann also die Entitäten sind. Es handelt sich also nicht wie bei Rhein oder dem benannten Flug um Einzelvertreter, sondern um eine Typbezeichnung. Also ist *Thread-Klasse* richtig.

Comment: @falkb Eine Klasse (Sammlung/Bauplan/...) ist auch eine Entität, im Sinne von ["existierendes, benennbares Ding"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entit%C3%A4t). Sie hat einen Namen, sie existiert, sie kann sogar in vielen Sprachen, wie auch C++, Daten und Methoden beinhalten. Mir ist klar, dass es in der Informatik einen anderen, enger gefassten Entitätsbegriff gibt, ich beziehe mich jedoch auf den des allgemeinen Sprachgebrauchs, nachdem selbst abstrakte Konzepte Entitätscharakter haben können.